# Polymer: observing property change for an array with data binding

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, observers

In `my-custom-element`, I am trying to compute a property (`computedProperty`) based on a second property (`selected`). This second property is binded to the property (`selected-values`) of  a child element (`iron-selector`). Since the property observed is of type Array I am [expecting](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation) the `selected.*` syntax to work. It does not.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">

<dom-module id="my-custom-element">

  <style>
    :host ::content .iron-selected {
      background-color: orange;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <div>logged:<span id='logged'></span></div>
    <div>computed:<span id='computed'>{{computedProperty}}</span></div>
    <iron-selector multi selected-values="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="uid">
        <div class="select-option" uid="foo">foo</div>
        <div class="select-option" uid="bar">bar</div>
        <div class="select-option" uid="baz">baz</div>
    </iron-selector>
    <button on-tap="log">Log</button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-custom-element',
      properties: {
        selected: {
          type: Array,
          default: function () { return []; }
        },
        computedProperty: {
          type: String,
          computed: 'compute(selected.*)'
        }
      },
      compute: function(selected) {
        return this.selected.join();
      },
      log: function() {
        return this.$.logged.textContent = this.selected.join();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

As I can check with the log button, the value of the `selected` property is properly propagated to through the binding though.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would love to do  a plunker to allow people to play arount with it. But I don't see of to link to the iron-selector folder on github...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a fix that resolves the binding issue:

https://github.com/Trakkasure/iron-selector/tree/fix-multiselect

I've made a pull request to get this fix in.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I updated the dependencies in my  `bower.json` with `"iron-selector": "Trakkasure/iron-selector#fix-multiselect"` and ran `bower update` but it does not solve my issue. I am trying to figure out how to write a unit test for this issue.

Comment: Can you give me more detail on this? I was able to take your code and get the results you expected. [JSBin code](http://jsbin.com/zotafo/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: I just `bower update` again and it works perfectly now! Thanks. (The update moved my local version from commit `9f40405` to commit `6dba53131b` so I am not sure why I did not work before!)